# Flutter Social sign in with Cognito web UI and Facebook policy

Tags: facebook, amazon-cognito

Followed all steps in this page for Facebook login with Web UI
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/social_signin_web_ui/q/platform/flutter/

And app was working fine, the problem that after while Facebook disable the app since the callback only work on mobile devices and not on the web.

What's the best approach to solve this issue?

Comment: Any solution I am also facing the same issue

Comment: Any solutions? I am facing the same issue and my application is continuously rejected in the facebook review process.

Comment: @sunilkumar Did you able to find any solutions? Then please let us know.